# What does “takes advantage of their head rope runs the risk” mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage, translation, literature, spanish

The fol­low­ing line is from the 2015 trans­la­tion from the Span­ish
of [des­a­pa­re­ci­do](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/desaparecido)
Ar­gen­tine writer [Ha­rol­do
Con­ti](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haroldo_Conti)’s 1962 novel,
*South­easter* (orig­i­nal Span­ish ti­tle, *Sud­este*):

> This wretched habit makes them think the place is theirs, and the
> un­sus­pect­ing soul **who takes ad­van­tage of their head rope runs the
> risk they’ll sink his boat,** and with gun­fire, too.

Could some kind soul please ex­plain the part I’ve placed in bold above?

Comment: Someone runs a risk of sinking their boat. Who is it? It is some unsuspecting soul. Why? Because that unsuspecting soul took advantage of their head rope. What the hell is a head rope? I don't know. it's some sailing term I think.

Comment: This story was translated from Spanish. Since I can't find any applicable meaning of "head rope" in English, it seems likely that "head rope" is a translation of some Spanish phrase, probably related to fishing.

Comment: @PeterShor See: "... [Other commercial ropes](https://www.novabraid.com/rope-types/fishing-rope/) for specific fisheries include trawl lines, **head ropes**, purse seine lines, weed lines,"

Comment: But why would stealing fish from a fishing net be "taking advantage of the head rope"?

Comment: If the story was originally in Spanish, then I suspect the key word was _aprovechar_...so it might be a clumsy translation.

Comment: There seems to be an answer to the same question [here](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/takes-advantage-of-their-head-rope-runs-the-risk.3843579/).

Comment: I think it may be impossible to figure out the exact meaning from the translation. The right way to solve this is to find the original Spanish. It's Haroldo Conti's *Sudeste*, and I can't find an online version in Spanish.

Comment: @PeterShor Yes I also have problems finding the original. It would certainly be helpful!

Comment: @Cascabel: the Spanish (via [Google books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Sudeste/8maPm3MMqckC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=sudeste%20conti)): "Esta maldita costumbre los ha hecho sentirse dueños del lugar y el desprevenido que se monta sobre la relinga corre peligro de que le hundan el bote a tiros."

Comment: @   Yup, _montar_  the _relinga_" idicates "riding along the rope" @PeterShor...fantastic dtective work!

Comment: @Cascabel: I don't need to post my own answer — it's better to have just one good answer, so you should edit yours.

Answer (score 7):

This is slightly ambiguous...

*Head* has several meanings on boats and sailing ships. The usage  that most all recognize describes  a "2-holer" traditionally (and conveniently) located at the *front* of the ship. However, the word can also indicate *top.*

In this case, 'Head *rope*' could be  a type of line that is attached to  the top edge of the sail, but as these are fisherman I suspect that  *on a fishing boat it is the line running along the top of the net*.¹

(Please note that the word *rope* is not usually  used  on a boat unless it has a specific name and usage: once it is brought onboard and put to use it is referred to as *line*.)

The full [context of the quote](http://bookanista.com/delta/):

> In any case, there’s nothing more daft than taking note of references like these. If there are certain fishermen who come to lay their nets here, at night, and in the week, it’s owing more to the fact that the area is little frequented at those times. This wretched habit makes them think the place is theirs, and the unsuspecting soul ***who takes advantage of their head rope runs the risk they’ll sink his boat***, and with gunfire, too.

If you read a little further...

> He bottom-trawled his nets across this very stretch of sandbank, seizing on a surge, and once out on the open sea he pulled the catch on board.

The fisherman is fishing near the mouth of the channel, and hauls up his catch once out of it.

---

A valuable contribution and [primary source](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Sudeste/8maPm3MMqckC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=sudeste%20conti) from [Peter Shor](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/5754/peter-shor)...From the original Spanish:
*"Esta maldita costumbre los ha hecho sentirse dueños del lugar y el desprevenido que se **monta sobre la relinga** corre peligro de que le hundan el bote a tiros."*

...which translates to **"run along the head rope".**

---

### Summarizing

Apparently there  are locals taking advantage of the fish trapped in the nets. It appears  they are in small craft using the head rope to pull themselves along, thus "taking advantage"². If they are on the inside of the head rope they run the risk of being capsized when the trawler begins hauling in the catch.  The fishermen keep shotguns on board to to repel them. It is mentioned that one of these kept a Purdey shotgun for this purpose.

---

#### Footnotes

1. Although [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/headrope) has it as obsolete, I still see [ads for this type of line](https://www.novabraid.com/rope-types/fishing-rope/) being advertised on the web. in fact, the the Spanish definitions from RAE are almost identical to Merriam Webster.²  [See DRAE](https://dle.rae.es/relinga?m=form), which reads:

   > ***relinga***
   >
   > 1. *f. Mar.* Cada una de las cuerdas o sogas en que van colocados los plomos y corchos con que se calan y sostienen las redes en el agua.
   > 2. *f. Mar.* Cabo con que se refuerzan las orillas de las velas.

   It is RAE sense 1 that the author used in the original, because that is the sense that pertains to fishing nets not to sails.

   In its June 2021 (last month!) update to its [entry for *head rope*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/84970), the OED marks as obsolete only the two senses related to ① either of a pair of shrouds, or ② a line for hoisting a flag up the masthead. The two senses exactly corresponding to those for *relinga* in the RAE, the OED gives recent citations for. One is for the bolt-rope at the top of a sail. but the other is the top-rope running along a fishing net, which is the use here.

   It notes cognates in Middle Dutch, Old Saxon, and Anglo-Norman:

   > Compare Middle Dutch *hōvetreep* principal rope of a tent (Dutch †*hoofdreep* large rope used on a gun carriage), Old Saxon *hōvidrēp* principal rope (apparently on a ship).

   RAE says *ralinga* was originally taken from Dutch. The sense used with nets it notes postdates the term *head-roping* for the same, suggesting a back derivation.
2. Clarification:

   Apparently this comes from a translation from Spanish. I had been  assuming that the original contained the word *aprovechar*, which often has negative connotations. However, In this case it appears that the locals were using the head rope to maneuver their smaller boats, thus creating a drag on the line.

   This supports the "run along the head rope" idea.

   In my opinion, the translation is confusing and not very accurate.

Answer (score 4):

I'm reasonably confident that they are talking about filching fish trapped by the trawl. During a tide surge into a bay through a narrow neck, there will be a lot of flow. You just park the net in the neck and let the tide deliver the fish. This is easy on the equipment compared to dragging over the bottom.

Now if you happen to be living in a shack thereabouts, it's a bit of a temptation to dip a few of the fish trapped by the net. That's what I read in "taking advantage of the headrope" - it's easy fishing, and might get you shot at.